# Vue: two params in url not loading correct route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, parameters, router

Comunity

I have a list of bookings (component: BookingListItem), which I render in my component "BookingView". Now I want to show the booking details when I click on one of these booking items.
For this, I created a streched link, like that:

```
<router-link
      :to="`patients/${this.user.id}/bookings/${booking.booking_id}`"
      class="stretched-link"
    ></router-link>
```

I need the userid and the bookingid to make an api call from the ReadBookingView component (in this component the bookingdetails are displayed).

In my router.js file I defined the route like that:

```
    {
      path: "/patients/:userid/bookings/:bookingid",
      name: "readbooking",
      component: ReadBookingView,
    },
```

But when I load my BookingView component the following warnings are showed: [image]
There the userid and the bookingid are correct. But when I click on one of my booking items the following link is opened: http://URL:8081/4328

I hope y'all understand my explanation. Cause I don't understand why it's not loading correcty and I am very grateful for all your inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<router-link
      :to="`/patients/${this.user.id}/bookings/${booking.booking_id}`"
      class="stretched-link"
    ></router-link>
```

Comment: oh god, this was the mistake... *facepalm*. Thank you so much!!

Comment: No worries. Please accept the answer if it solved your question.